# prepare statement object is not closed

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Is that code affecting the Performance or cause any memory leaks? Here `PreparedStatement` object is not closed and doesn’t have the reference to close. Any suggestion on this?

```
private ResultSet getEmpData(String query){
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        rs = connection.prepareStatement(query).executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}

public int getEmployeeSalary(){

    ResultSet rs = null;
    int salary  = 0 ;
    try {
        rs = getEmpData("SELECT SALARY FROM EMP WHERE NAME ='SAM'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            salary = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }finally{
        if (rs!= null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're closing the `ResultSet`, you're not closing the `PreparedStatement` statement that is associated with it. What you should be doing in your `finally` block is the following:

```
rs.getStatement().close();
```

This would ensure that the associated statement is closed. Also as per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29),

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
> that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
> result from a sequence of multiple results.

This means that when you close the statement object using the aforementioned code, you're also effectively closing the ResultSet object.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should not be closing your ResultSet but rather the database connection itself.  This should not cause a memory leak provided you close your database connection when you have completed our database operations.